# OpenID What to pick, and why?

Tags: php, openid

I've been thinking of to start using OpenID on my website, so that my visitors can login and feel secure, with credentials they already, for example use to login to Facebook or Google with.

I've been looking at: [OpenID Library](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)

Under the section PHP. Then I thought it would maybe be one or two things to choose. But it seems like I'm wrong.

> So my question is: What should I pick for my site?

At my website you can login, and then you have your own profile with picture and stuff. While logged in you can write a bulletin. And ofc it's created with PHP.

Actually I would love to have Google and Facebook as the ways to login.

Comment: I don't believe facebook supports openid does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is no OpenID provider. You can only log into FB itself, if you've already got an OpenID from elsewhere. If you want people to use their FB account to log into your own site, you need to use FB's API or some middleware like [Janrain's Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage).

Google on the other hand is an OpenID provider, so your users could use their Google accounts to log into your site using only OpenID.

The rest is up to you. And TBH, you should have asked here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/